# How can I run an EXE from a Network Share?

Tags: windows-7, security, network-shares

I have the network share \server\me mounted as H:

There are executable in directories there.

I try to run them in cmd.exe

```
H:\somedir>program
Access is denied.
```

I've read that it is possibly related to the "Local Intranet" and "Trusted Sites" settings in the Security tab of "Internet Options". I've added file:///H:/ to "Trusted Sites" and this automatically translated to file:///*.server

I still get "Access is denied."

How can I run an EXE from a Network Share and/or a mapped network drive?

Double clicking the EXE in windows explorer first gives me the "publisher could not be verified" warning. After I click "Run" in that dialog, I get "Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file.  You may not have the appropriate permissions to access the item."

Comment: Hey Jay, I'm betting it's local permissions on the folder and share permissions across the network. You have to have read and execute privilege to allow remote execution. Check the folder properties locally on the H drive and also check the share permissions. As a test, you can set yourself for full control over the folder and full control over share permissions. This will help confirm permissions issues. Be careful though as you don't want to leave it too open with full permissions for other users.

Comment: was reading your story in your profile   there's a cliffhanger here "Age 14 in 1990, Dad buys the family - me - my first “PC”, a 4........"   If superuser has a limit, can you put it in on www.pastebin.com and link to it?

Comment: @barlop ha! sorry about that. see my blog about page: jrwren.wrenfam.com/blog/about-me/

Answer (score 3):

- Go to your remote share directory from the machine that its installed on.
- Right-click on it.
- Select properties.
- Open security tab.
- Click advanced.
- Click change permissions.
- If you don't see your name in there, click add; if you do, then double-click on your user.
- Make sure, if  `full control` and `allow` are not already checked, that at least the `traverse`, `list`, `read attrs`, `read extended attrs`, and `read permissions` are checked for your user.
- If you don't have permissions to check off these permissions, then you **will need to gain admin access** before making these adjustments, or at least gain ownership.
- After you have made these adjustments, delete and remap the network drive, put in the credentials that MATCH the credentials of the user account for which you just set the permissions.
- You will now have read permission when you share, so long as you are authenticated as that user the first time it asks you for the credentials.

Answer (score -2):

Try using `pushd` command to refer to the directory path in remote machine.

For example, if your remote machine having the exe to be executed is called `abc-pc` and the folder containing the file is shared with name my-share, then in the cmd prompt of your machine you can type

```
c:>pushd \\abc-pc\my-share R:\
```

By using above method windows creates a temporary drive called `R` and you can run the exe present in R drive.

```
R:\runmyfile.exe
```

Like previous answer make sure you have access rights to run the file. This can be verified by logging on abc-pc as admin and verifying the properties on file. The properties like read, execute needs to have your username in it