# EXE on a network drive - how to create a shortcut on taskbar?

Tags: windows, taskbar, shortcuts, file-shortcut

I've created a .bat file that runs the network exe, but it does not allow it to be made a shortcut on the taskbar:

Within my `runme.bat` file:
`cmd /c start w:\programs\app.exe`

That does not work.

I've also tried creating a shortcut of the `w:\programs\app.exe` onto the desktop, but Explorer won't allow that either to be made a shortcut on the taskbar.

Besides the obvious of copying the exe to a local drive, how to I get this shortcut created?

Comment: Does this answer your question ? https://superuser.com/a/904379/598567

Comment: You can put .LNK shortcuts on the task bar, but not .BAT shortcuts. So far as I remember the latter has not been possible.

Comment: @KalamalkaKid I can run it, i need to create a link to it

Comment: @John But if I create a .LNK file on the desktop, it cannot be added to the taskbar.